# How to deploy virtual machine image in ova format from URL to Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have Virtual Machine image in .ova format. Image file is available by URL.
Actually it is available from Amazon S3 store URL:

```
https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/datasci/Coursera-Data-Science-Ubuntu.ova
```

Please suggest can I deploy and run this image as EC2 instance?

So I have additional requirement - I don't want to download 2-3 Gb ova file to my machine just to upload it back to AWS.

Answer (score -1):

EC2 does support import with the following formats:

> You can import VMware ESX and VMware Workstation VMDK images, Citrix
>   Xen VHD images and Microsoft Hyper-V VHD images for Windows Server
>   2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server
>   2008 R2. You can export previously imported EC2 instances to VMware
>   ESX VMDK, VMware ESX OVA, Microsoft Hyper-V VHD or Citrix Xen VHD file
>   formats. We plan to support import for additional operating systems,
>   versions and virtualization infrastructure products in the future.

In order to do this however, you need to download the images and use the command line tools. You should be able to do that on an ec2 instance as well which will have much faster download speed.

If your image is running linux, you cannot use the import tools. Instead you would have to launch your VM and use the ec2 tools to bundle your image.